# How to Schedule a publish date and time

Tags: nodes

How do I schedule a publishing date for a node I've created but don't want to publish until a certain date/time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [scheduler module](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler). This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified dates.